# I want my buttons to be flat on top with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

[Buttons that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuIXt.png)

[My current buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRqQz.png)

This is what I want, but currently I can only make them fully round with no flat top. Lost the code to this and am wondering if anyone knows how to do this?

Sorry if I did something wrong posting this, never posted here before

Comment: you can add border radius.

Comment: Hi, can you post your codes here? I believe you should be able to reproduce it, even if you lose the code. You may want to check this [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a border-radius to the button.

```css
button {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```